# Selector function erroring in initial undefined state

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux

I am making a form where you type in the movie title to search, and you get the movie back from the state that has all movies. I am currently trying to create a selector that selects just the movie from the state, that has the same title as the search query. I call my selector method in `mapStateToProps` in my `<MovieForm />` component, which I have seen in a tutorial, but I believe it is erroring out upon the initial state rendering.

I have tried using if statements on the state in the selector, as well as in mapState to props, so that if the state is undefined it returns the state, but I still get the error.

EDIT: This errors initially, before any GET_MOVIE_SUCCESS has been run

selectors.js

```
export function selectMovieFromMovies(state, title) {
  return {
    moviesById: state.moviesById.map(movie => movie.title.toString() === title)
  };
}
```

MovieForm.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, title) => {
  console.log("state in mapState:", state);
  return {
    moviesById: selectMovieFromMovies(state, title)
  };
};
```

relevant part of reducer: movies.js

```
const initialState = {
  moviesById: []
};

function movieReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_MOVIE_SUCCESS":
      console.log("action.json.movies:", action);
      return {
        ...state,
        moviesById: action.json.movies
      };
```

Error in browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at selectMovieFromMovies (selectors.js:4)
    at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (MovieForm.js:43)
```

Comment: in the code you posted `map` isn't used at all, and your error say `map` of undefined, please check again did you posted proper data or proper error

Comment: fixed. was an artifact of a past attempt.

Comment: `console.log("state in mapState:", state);` what this line prints ?

Comment: ```state in mapState: 
{ingredientsReducer: {…}, recipesReducer: {…}, movieReducer: {…}}
ingredientsReducer: {ingredientsById: Array(0)}
movieReducer: {moviesById: Array(0)}
recipesReducer: {recipesById: Array(0)}
__proto__: Object```

Comment: You need to access it using `state.movieReducer.moviesById.map(movie => movie.title.toString() === title)`

Comment: or pass it like `selectMovieFromMovies(state.movieReducer, title)`

Comment: Solved! Was not using the proper query. Thanks a lot @CodeManiac

Answer (score 0):

This example isn't directly using Redux, but the principle should hold.

Are you certain that when the `GET_MOVIE_SUCCESS` action is dispatched that it is setting the movies properly? At some point it's becoming `undefined`:

```js
function selectMovieFromMovies(state, title) {
  return {
    moviesById: state.moviesById.map(movie => movie.title.toString() === title)
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, title) => {
  console.log("state in mapState:", state);
  return {
    moviesById: selectMovieFromMovies(state, title)
  };
};

const initialState = {
  moviesById: []
};

function movieReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_MOVIE_SUCCESS":
      console.log("action.json.movies:", action);
      return {
        ...state,
        moviesById: action.json.movies
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

let state = movieReducer(undefined, {
  type: "INIT"
});
console.log(state);
let mapState = mapStateToProps(state, "anything");
console.log(mapState);
state = movieReducer(state, {
  type: "GET_MOVIE_SUCCESS",
  json: {}
});
console.log(state);
mapState = mapStateToProps(state, "anything"); // throws: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
console.log(mapState);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not typing the correct path to my state. Thanks to @CodeManiac for solution

selectors.js BEFORE

```
export function selectMovieFromMovies(state, title) {
  return {
    moviesById: state.moviesById.map(movie => movie.title.toString() === title)
  };
}
```

selectors.js AFTER

```
export function selectMovieFromMovies(state, title) {
  return {
   moviesById: state.movieReducer.moviesById.map(movie => movie.title.toString() === title)
 };
}
```